# JQgrid array data sorting

Tags: arrays, ajax, sorting, jqgrid, local

I'm hoping this is not a duplicate question, but none of the similar questions got my grid to work.

```
            $("#list1").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: tile_height,
        width: tile_width,
        colNames:["Name","Email", "Telephone", "Branch","Position"],
        colModel:[
            {name:'name',index:'name', sorttype: "text", sortable:true},
            {name:'email',index:'email', formatter:'email', sorttype: "text", sortable:true},
            {name:'tel_nos',index:'tel_nos', sorttype: "text", sortable:true},      
            {name:'branch_name',index:'branch_name', sorttype: "text", sortable:true},      
            {name:'user_occ',index:'user_occ', sorttype: "text", sortable:true}     
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'name',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        emptyrecords : 'No Record Found',
        onSelectRow: function(ids) {                
            window.location.href = "staffedit.php?op=viewstaff&id=" + $(this).getGridParam('selrow');
        }
    });

var mydata = [{"uid":"1","user_occ":"Operations Manager","email":"email.com","name":"name","tel_nos":"555","branch_name":"branch_name"},{"uid":"2","user_occ":"Operations Manager","email":"email.com","name":"name","tel_nos":"555","branch_name":"branch_name"},{"uid":"3","user_occ":"Operations Manager","email":"email.com","name":"name","tel_nos":"555","branch_name":"branch_name"}];
for(var i=0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
            $("#list1").jqGrid("addRowData", mydata[i].uid ,mydata[i]);
        }
```

This works perfectly on first load... all the records show, with the scroll bar on the side. When i try to sort on any column though, sorting is not 100%, but worst is it loses a lot of records... it just disappears... I limited the SQL creating the local data array to 10 then it works perfect the sorting, and it does not loose any data. Limit to 100, scroll bar appears on first load, looks good, but on sort, it sorts OK, but shows only about 20 records... take off limit (about 1500 records) same problem, sort very bad now (I can see some sorting but not 100%), and again only see 20 records, no scroll bar, and without pagination (which i don't want like the first load) I cannot see the other records.

Can someone please guide me to the correct settings?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scrapping the local data idea and went for the ajax remote data approach.
this worked fine... sorting fine, no records lost.
I guess the local data sorting function is a big buggy with bigger datasets ???